# search a node of an xml file

Tags: vb.net, .net-4.8

I make a script in VB.net framework 4.8.
I would like to make a script that allow to search in an xml file if a node exists or not:

I would like to find if the name of one of the parameters already exists.

Here is the xml file :

```
<MACHINE>
  <NAME />
  <RECIPE>
    <NAME>
      <PARAMETER>
        <NAME>Angledubras</NAME>
        <ACCESS_LEVEL />
        <HISTO_DAY_MAX />
        </HISTORY>
      </PARAMETER>
      <PARAMETER>
        <NAME>Différence de hauteur entre le miroir et le doigt </NAME>
        <ACCESS_LEVEL />
        <HISTO_DAY_MAX />
        <HISTORY />
      </PARAMETER>
      <PARAMETER>
        <NAME>Vitesse pendant la correction</NAME>
        <ACCESS_LEVEL />
        <HISTO_DAY_MAX />
        <HISTORY />
      </PARAMETER>
    </NAME>
  </RECIPE>
</MACHINE>
```

Comment: I tried this with no success : nodeSearch=doc.SelectSingleNode("/MACHINE/RECIPE/NAME/PARAMETER[NAME='Angledubras']");

Answer (score 0):

The XML doesn't look right but this will find PARAMETER nodes with the NAME you want.

```
    Dim xe As XElement
    xe = XElement.Load("path here")

    'for testing use literal

    xe = <MACHINE>
             <NAME/>
             <RECIPE>
                 <NAME>
                     <PARAMETER>
                         <NAME>Angledubras</NAME>
                         <ACCESS_LEVEL/>
                         <HISTO_DAY_MAX/>
                     </PARAMETER>
                 </NAME>
                 <PARAMETER>
                     <NAME>Différence de hauteur entre le miroir et le doigt </NAME>
                     <ACCESS_LEVEL/>
                     <HISTO_DAY_MAX/>
                     <HISTORY/>
                 </PARAMETER>
                 <PARAMETER>
                     <NAME>Vitesse pendant la correction</NAME>
                     <ACCESS_LEVEL/>
                     <HISTO_DAY_MAX/>
                     <HISTORY/>
                 </PARAMETER>
             </RECIPE>
         </MACHINE>

    Dim ie As IEnumerable(Of XElement)

    ie = From el In xe.<RECIPE>...<PARAMETER>
           Where el.<NAME>.Value = "Angledubras"
           Select el
```